# Eclipse fails to import Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I tried to import a multi-module Maven project into Eclipse using the option "Existing Maven Project" from the Import menu.

I got this error:

```
Could not update project nbsocialmetrics-frontend configuration
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

In the problems pane I saw this error:

```
Project configuration is not up-to-date with pom.xml. 
Run Maven->Update Project or use Quick Fix. nbsocialmetrics-backend     line 1  Maven Configuration Problem
```

However when I ran Maven->Update Project I just kept getting this error:

```
Unable to update Maven configuration
Could not update project nbsocialmetrics-frontend configuration
java.lang.NullPointerException
Could not update project nbsocialmetrics-backend configuration
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The last repository checkin on this project had no issues so I can't figure out why Eclipse won't import it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how I resolved the problem:

1. Deleted the imported project from Eclipse (but did not remove from disk).
2. Exited Eclipse
3. Deleted the project's `.settings` directory
4. Deleted the projects's `.project` directory
5. Deleted the workspace's `.metadata` directory
6. Restarted Eclipse
7. Imported the Maven project again by using the option "Existing Maven Project" from the Import menu

This resolved the problem.

Comment: Yep, sometimes wiping everything out is the only chanche :-)

Comment: Thanks for the validation @watery.  Is there other state Eclipse maintains on disk that can be wiped?

Comment: Oh, I just saw that you cleared the `.metadata` directory too. That's a bit overkill, I guess. I think that removing the project (I usually remove even the data from disk) should be enough in these cases.

Comment: Hi @watery, actually clearing the `.metadata` directory was necessary in my case.  I don't know why but I tried without doing that and it didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Nine months later and this solution solved my problem again.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following maven-jar-plugin to the pom.xml fixes this problem. See  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=516887

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks, if I ever work on this code again I'll verify your solution.